# C++ Dynamically Allocated Array-Way in over my head

Tags: c++, dynamic-arrays

So I have an assignment to read in a text file that contains four pieces of information about a person, which are separated by commas. I am attempting to read in the file, which is called "lab8.txt", break up the information, and then allow the user to view the information as well as be able to modify the information. For now I am focused on getting the information out of the text file and being able to display this information to the user. I have several errors throughout the code and was hoping someone could help me fix these mistakes and tell me what I was doing wrong. Any and all help is appreciated. The text file looks like this. I am sorry I know this is alot to ask but assignment was created by someone other than my professor and my class is much farther behind than the professors class who made this assignment.

> > M123456789, Smith,Joe,1978/12/30,  M2345689,Jones,Marc,1980/01/28,
> >     M000022,Bach,Johann,1685/03/31,  M000024,Mozart,Wolfgang,1791/01/27,
> >     M000023,Handel,George,1759/04/14,  M222222,Geisel,Theodor,1904/03/02,
> >     M000044,Sousa,Philip,1854/11/06,  M000046,The Frog,Kermit,1955/05/09,
> >     M000049,Piggy,Miss,1974/10/13,  M000049,Piggy,Miss,1974/10/13,
> >     M000043,Henson,James,1936/09/24,

And my code includes three portions. A main function, a header file, and a cpp file for all my function definitions. I will list them in that order.

// MAIN FUNCTION

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <classname.h>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    File var1;
    var1.MenuEditor();
}

#ifndef CLASSNAME_H_INCLUDED
#define CLASSNAME_H_INCLUDED
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct StudentData
{
    string StudentId;
    string LastName;
    string FirstName;
    string BirthDate;
};
```

// HEADER FILE

```
class File
{
    public:
        File();
        File(string);
        bool ReadRecordsFromFile(string);
        void MenuEditor();
        void SearchFile (string);
    private:
        int number_records;
        void BreakUp (string);
        void SortName (StudentData, string);
        StudentData allocate(string);
        void AddRecord(string);
        void DeleteRecord(string);
        void ModifyRecord(string);
        bool ReadRecordsFromFile(string fileName);
        void WriteRecordsToFile(string fileName);
};

#endif // CLASSNAME_H_INCLUDED
```

// CPP FILE WITH FUNCTION DEFINITIONS

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "classname.h"

using namespace std;
// This method returns a true if you can open the file or a false if you can
// not

// You will need to add calls to your methods to allocate the array and
// "breakup" the input string.
File::File(string fileName)
{

}

bool File::ReadRecordsFromFile(string fileName)
{
    string input_line;
    ifstream infile(fileName.c_str()); // This might be useful for you.

    if(!infile)
    {
        return false;
    }
    Records=new StudentData[100];

// number_of_records or some other variable to store current record count
    number_of_records = 0;
    while(getline(infile, input_line))
    {
// CHECK to see if you need to allocate or expand dynamic array here
//  - Use method defined in class to do the allocation
// Call Method to break up data stored in input_line
// and than store new data into dynamic array
//  - See Files++ code sample on blackboard

        string temp,MNum,
        int Current_comma= input_line.find(",");
        Records[number_of_records].StudentID = input_line.substr(0, Current_comma);
        temp= input_line.substr(Current_comma+1);
        cout << [number_of_records].StudentID <<endl;
        number_of_records = number_of_records + 1;
    }

    return true;
}

// This method returns a true if you can open the file for writing and
// false if not
bool Lab8::WriteRecordsToFile(string fileName)
{
    string output_line;
    ofstream outfile(fileName.c_str());

    if(!outfile)
    {
        return false;
    }

// number_of_records or some other variable to store current record count class
    for (int rec_count = 0; rec_count < number_of_records; rec_count++)
    {
// CREATE a seperate output line out of your data or create it inline
        fileobject << output_line << endl;
        number_of_records = number_of_records + 1;
    }
    outfile.close();

    return true;
}




File::StudentData allocate(string);
{

}


void File::AddRecord(string fileName)
{

}
void File::DeleteRecord(string fileName)
{

}

void File::ModifyRecord(string fileName)
{

}
void File::SortName(string fileName)
{

}
void File::SearchFile(string fileName)
{

}
void File::MenuEditor()
{
    ReadRecordsFromFile("lab8.txt")
    cout << "Press 1 to add file." <<endl;
    cout << "Press 2 to delete file." <<endl;
    cout << "Press 3 to modify file." <<endl;
    cout << "Press 4 to sort file." <<endl;
    cout << "Press 5 to search file." <<endl ;
    getline(cin,  int menuchoice);
    if (menuchoice == 1)
    {
        AddRecord();
    }
    else if(menuchoice == 2)
    {
        DeleteRecord();
    }
    else if(menuchoice == 3)
    {
        ModifyRecord();
    }
    else if(menuchoice == 4)
    {
        SearchFile();
    }
    else if(menuchoice == 5)
    {
        SortName();
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "You done messed up. Re run the program" << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: So what is the question... what are the issues you are having problems with?

Comment: The biggest thing is I dont believe the ReadFile function works and I have not been able to get it to display anything from the text file to the user in my main function.

Comment: What ReadFile function? No such thing exists above.. I only see `ReadRecordsFromFile("lab8.txt")` and it's missing a semi-colon.. No implementation..

Comment: Do you have a debugger you can use to trace through the function one line at a time?  Does it just fail to open the file and return false?  What is number_of_records after it finishes running?

Comment: Yes I do have a debugger and I have gotten several errors. "ReadRecordFromFiles can not be overloaded" "Records was not declared in this scope" "number_of_records was not declared in this scope"

Comment: Is the text file really a single line? csv files usually have one record per line.

Comment: If there are compiler errors, the compiler will tell you what the problem is, and the line it is at.  Are there any messages you don't understand?  With the debugger, you can trace through the program one line at a time, and check each variable that gets assigned.  Then you can focus on any lines where the debugger does something different to what you expected.

Comment: There are a ton of errors from looking at this.. File class does NOT have a `StudentData* Record` member. There are 100 `StudentData*` allocated to `Record` and accessed using the dot notation (should be `-> operator`). OP forgot to allocate each index to a `new StudentData()`. There is no destructor and `Record` leaks within the first function.. etc..

Comment: Ok here is what I wanna do. Can you guys help me focus on being able to read the file in and displaying it when the program is run. And no the text file is one record per line. I had trouble getting it to display that way when posting.

Comment: Is there a reason here to be using pointers and new, rather than the simpler and safer std::vector?  Is it just that the lecturer is teaching things backwards and doing pointers before containers?

Comment: Yes we just started pointers but I have not even heard of a container

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <fstream>    
class File
{
    public:
        File();
        *****File(string);********  change to File(&ifstream) <--- do this when passing a text file to a function. 
        bool ReadRecordsFromFile(string);
        void MenuEditor();
        void SearchFile (string);
    private:
        int number_records;
        void BreakUp (string);
        void SortName (StudentData, string);
        StudentData allocate(string);
        void AddRecord(string);
        void DeleteRecord(string);
        void ModifyRecord(string);
        bool ReadRecordsFromFile(string fileName);
        void WriteRecordsToFile(string fileName);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some hints:

The StudentData structure needs to be visible wherever it is used.  This should be in your header file - It may be, but it doesnt't appear to be the case the way you have presented it.

You have two ReadRecordsFromFile in your File class.  You can't have two of them with the same arguments, but one private and one public.  Remove one of them.

You need a StudentData* Records; in your File class.  This should be initialised to nullptr or zero in your constructor.

Your class defines number_records, but you use something called number_of_records.  You need to be consistent.  Also, this should be initialised to zero in your constructor.

You have inconsistent capitalisation in StudentId.  You really need to be precise and consistent on your variable names.

Your cout output in ReadRecordsFromFile doesn't say what variable you are writing out.  Presumably you meant Records

the return value of WriteRecordsToFile differs between the declaration and definition

fileobject is undeclared in WriteRecordsToFile  What file object did you mean? Maybe outfile??

File:: in the allocate method is in the wrong place, and having a semicolon at the end means its a declaration, not a definition.

Definition of SortName doesn't match its declaration.

In your call to getline you try to create a variable.  You can't do that inside parameters. You need to define it first.

getline returns strings not integers, so you'll either need to read in a string and compare against a string, or read in an integer.